# ES6 module: export before finishing definitions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm wondering if accessing `Foo.bar` from another file is guaranteed to be valid, because I'm "adding" a new attribute `bar` (e.g. act like a static member) to class `Foo` "after" exporting `Foo`.

```js
// foo.js

// we export Foo here
export class Foo {
    // ...
}

// note this is "added" after Foo's definition block
Foo.bar = 'a';
```

```js
// index.js
import { Foo } from './foo.js';
console.log(Foo.bar)' // 'a' or 'undefined'?
```

I tried it in Chrome and Firefox, it works fine (printing `a` instead of `undefined`), but I'm not sure if this is a valid syntax allowed by any **implementation-independent** ECMAScript?

I think this is related to how the standard asks JS interpreter interprets the module file `foo.js`: does it expose `Foo` to the importers as soon as it sees class `Foo` implementation's closing brace, or does it finish parsing the entire `foo.js` before exposing `Foo`?

Comment: It's valid. It parses the file and then returns the module

Comment: It's valid as far as your example goes. Watch out for circular dependencies though: that is one case where you *can* reference something before it's defined with imports/exports, and the circularity isn't always obvious (A imports B which imports C which imports D which imports A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does finish parsing before returning a module. It has to because in the same file you could have more `export`s one after another. So it is valid syntax and should work in browsers that support ESModules.

As I've shown in the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-driscoll-8ozcq), the `foo.js` file is parsed first, then the module is returned in the `index.js`. You can check it in the console. First the

```
parsed whole foo.js file
```

log appears, then the

```
now printing Foo.bar a
```

shows up. So as you can see, it's valid to refer to exported objects after the `exports` keyword.